# On a slow mobile connection attempting to open the notifications before fully loaded disables the button permanently

Tags: bug, notifications, mobile-web, global-inbox

When on a slow mobile connection (30+ second page load time) the page appears to finish loading but the load bar still has a small amount to go. If there are inbox notifications the temptation is to try to open the inbox.

Clicking on the inbox while the page is still loading does nothing [that’s fine; its still loading] however having done so even after the page fully loads the inbox remains disabled until the page is *completely reloaded* (so annother 30+ seconds). On the slow connection this can be infuriating.

> **Test System:**
>   Samsung Galaxy S3 - Android
>   Standard Browser

<sup>I expect this happens on all connections but the window of vulnerability is tiny on fast connections</sup>

Comment: We are going to move a lot of cheese in this area very soon, so this will be taken under advisement at that point.

Comment: I've removed the status-review tag because mobile web is no longer active. If you're still having issues with mobile access to our sites, please feel free to ask a new question.